# Xcode 4 iOS 4.3 download keeps stopping just prior to completion

Tags: ios, xcode, download

I keep trying to download Xcode 4 with iOS 4.3 SDK and after about 16 hours and 3.1 GB the download stops--before the entire 4.3 GB of the IMG file makes it. It's happened three times now. I turned the computer sleep setting to never so that should have allowed it to complete. There were no power glitches in the last two attempts. The incomplete IMG file and its companion IMG.part file remain sitting in the download folder. Double clicking on the IMG brings up an "IMG not recognized" error message.  Anyone else running into this problem and have a solution? I don't think it's an ISP problem because I was able to completely download the Xcode 3 iOS 4.3 SDK image and it's also around 4 GB. I appreciate any assistance.

Phil

P.S. Does Apple offer a physical DVD available for shipment? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: BTW, I was using Firefox for the download. I'm now using Opera. Opera has the ability to restart an partial download from the point where it stopped, so this might work. Still, if you know have better solution, please share.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting the computer? If Opera doesn't work out for you, and your willing to shell out 5 bucks, try downloading it from the Mac App Store. I have no idea why this would happen, I have downloaded it on multiple computers and not encountered any problems. Hope this helps, sorry I can't suggest more.

Comment: Now that you mention it, my MacBook's been on nonstop for the past several days while repeatedly trying to download so rebooting is certainly worth trying. I'll try downloading from the Mac App store if iGetter option doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I use iGetter to download the XCode with SDK. It provides higher download speed and availability to resume in case internet connection is interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of the respondents. I was finally able to download the entire image. It took rebooting and using Opera (to restart the download after it failed once). Overall, it took four days and at four attempts to get the entire image to download. Thanks again!

Phil